How do I scroll in an overflowing flexbox child, when my cursor is anywhere on my webpage?
I've been trying to build a web developer portfolio website, and am working on a layout in which my body is a flexbox with two main elements:

On the left, a basic navigation bar

On the right, a content box with section IDs that tie to the navigation bar.


What's working: The content box overflows the parent container as desired, and I can scroll through the content smoothly with my scroll wheel if my cursor is over the content box. With smooth scroll enabled, I can click on the IDs in the nav bar, and fluidly scroll to the relevant sections.
My problem: I want the content box to scroll when I move the scroll wheel, no matter where the cursor is on the webpage - e.g. in the navigation bar, in the margins -  as opposed to only scrolling if the cursor is in the content box. Once enabled, I want to maintain smooth scrolling for navigation bar clicks and scroll wheel scrolls.
I'm hoping someone can help me work this out, as I am unfortunately out of ideas! It feels like there may be a simple solution here, that I can't see yet.  : )
What I have tried:
I tried adding event listeners to the content box element to 1) prevent the default scroll and 2) force the content box to scroll no matter where the cursor is. While this does enable me to scroll the content box with the cursor outside of the content box as desired, and maintains smooth scrolling for navigation bar clicks, I lose smooth scrolling for scroll wheel scrolls, which is undesirable.
I was expecting to be able to scroll the content box from anywhere, and maintain smooth scrolling for both nav bar clicks and scroll wheel scrolls.
I've included the faulty script below so that you can see what I mean. I tried to force the wheel events into the scroll section. This does successfully force the scroll section to scroll when the cursor is not in the scroll section (e.g. in the nav bar), but the scrolls are very disjoint and non-fluid, resulting in a very poor user experience.


/*let mainContent = document.querySelector('.scrollSection');

function preventDefaultScroll(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function enableFlexScroll(event) {
  mainContent.scrollTop += event.deltaY;
}

document.addEventListener('wheel', preventDefaultScroll, {
  passive: false
});
document.addEventListener('wheel', enableFlexScroll, {
  passive: false
});*/
/* Flex container */

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* LHS Navigation */

.staticSection {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}


/* RHS Scrolling Content */

.scrollSection {
  width: 75%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#about,
#experience,
#projects {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
<div class="staticSection">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#experience">EXPERIENCE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="scrollSection" id="srollSection">
  <div id="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="experience">
    <h1>Experience</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="projects">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
  </div>
</div>




In both Firefox and Chrome, I can scroll the content of the snippet above with the mouse wheel, no matter where the mouse cursor actually points. Therefor, not sure what you are actually asking?

Hi @CBroe , thanks for taking a look at this! The JS should have been commented out, apologies. Correct that the JS allows it to scroll from anywhere, but the scrolls are not fluid and very disjoint. I included the JS snippet as an example of a solution that doesn't really work, because it introduces a different problem. I have commented out the code in the post, and now if you run the snippet at full screen, you should see the behaviour I describe?

Rather than having a scrolling div, just allow the body to scroll, and keep the navigation menu in place using sticky or fixed positioning. No Javascript is needed.


html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 1em 10%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}

nav {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav>div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  background: darkgray;
}

#about,
#experience,
#projects {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 1px 1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
<nav>
  <div>
    <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#experience">EXPERIENCE</a>
    <a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a>
  </div>
</nav>

<main>
  <div id="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="experience">
    <h1>Experience</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="projects">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
  </div>
</main>




great solution, thank you for the help Brett!
